# How to give an XL Work sheet name into a DataTable Using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms

I am exporting three worked sheet in single XL file. But I am getting a worksheet name like Table1, Table2, Table3.

Below is the C# code for without calling database, working correctly sheet names.

```
   var ds = new DataSet();
   var dt = new DataTable("TableName For Sheet1");
   dt.Columns.Add("col1");
   dt.Columns.Add("col2");
   dt.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value2");

   var dt2 = new DataTable("TableName For Sheet2");
   dt2.Columns.Add("col1");
   dt2.Columns.Add("col2");
   dt2.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value2");
   ds.Tables.Add(dt);
   ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
   ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "test.xls", Page.Response);
```

Below is the C# code for calling database stored procedure, but sheet names are given Table1, Table2, Table2.

```
    DataSe ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Registration Details");
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Education Details");
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Employeement Details");


    dt = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate(bo);
    gv_Regdetails.DataSource = dt;
    gv_Regdetails.DataBind();
    dt1 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate1(bo);
    dt2 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate2(bo);
    DataTable filteredEducation = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                     .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
                               .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim()))
                               .CopyToDataTable();
    DataTable filteredEmployee = dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                    .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
                              .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim()))
                              .CopyToDataTable();

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ds.Tables.Add(filteredEducation);
    ds.Tables.Add(filteredEmployee);
    ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "DangoteUsers.xls", Page.Response);
```

I need sheet names results like Registration Details,Education Details and Employeement Details.

I refer this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31516/Export-DataSet-to-Multiple-Excel-Sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `dt`, `dt1` and `dt2` after initialization and that is why you are not getting the names correctly and instead you are getting the default name for the tables. Try setting the name for those three tables after assignation or include the table name in the assignation logic. I updated your code to demonstrate this.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();


var dt = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate(bo);
gv_Regdetails.DataSource = dt;
gv_Regdetails.DataBind();
var dt1 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate1(bo);
var dt2 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate2(bo);
DataTable filteredEducation = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim()))
                           .CopyToDataTable();
DataTable filteredEmployee = dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
                          .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim()))
                          .CopyToDataTable();

dt.TableName = "Registration Details";
filteredEducation.TableName = "Education Details";
filteredEmployee.TableName = "Employeement Details";

ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(filteredEducation);
ds.Tables.Add(filteredEmployee);
ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "DangoteUsers.xls", Page.Response);
```

Comment: Can you update you answer, according my code. @Martin

Comment: See the update answer. It might be better to return the datatable with the appropriate name from your methods like `Get_Registrationdetailsbydate`

Comment: Ya, i got answer, how to return datatable. @Martin

Comment: Some data is missing in xl second sheet second method that means education details, why?. @Martin

Comment: That is difficult to say without knowing about the logic and without you explaining me the details.

Comment: Shall i explain the logic. @Martin

Comment: Could you please create a new question? That way it could be solved much faster and also the discussion will be more relevant.

Comment: Already I Created, I think you only will be answer, question link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031889/some-data-is-missing-in-the-export-to-excel-using-datatable-and-linq  . @Martin

Comment: Are you checking, I am waiting for your reply from that new question. @Martin